# database connection string with a button with a c# file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

in the program there must be a request for these things:
-server name

- database name
- id
- password.
  then there are two keys one makes you connect to the database and the other disconnects.

I'm looking for a way to do the above, I don't know about it.
this is program:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server; Initial Catalog=ACE_db; User Id=m.nastasi; Password=Mirko.123!");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Login where Data Source='" + textBox1.Text + "'; Initial Catalog='" + textBox2.Text + "'; ID='" + textBox3.Text + "' and Password='" + textBox4.Text + "' ",con); 
        
        
        
        this.Hide();

        Main ss = new Main();
        ss.show();
```

Comment: You seem to mix a sql statement with the connection string. Tip (if I understand the issue correctly) [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder)

Answer (score 1):

Since the code you provided is limited and the description is not very clear. According to your request, I re-wrote a simple sqlserver connection tool using Winforms. If you have any more information to add please let me know.

code show as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 
namespace Navicate
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string server, databaseName, userid, password;
 
        SqlConnection conn;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox4.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            server = textBox1.Text;
            databaseName = textBox2.Text;
            userid = textBox3.Text;
            password = textBox4.Text;
            if (server == "" && databaseName == "" && userid == "" && password == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill in the database connection information completely");
            }
            else
            {
                if(OpenConnection(server, databaseName, userid, password))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Database connection successed");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Database connection failed");
                }
 
            }
        }
 
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
            if (OpenConnection(server, databaseName, userid, password))
            {
                CloseConnection();
                MessageBox.Show("Database disconnected");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please connect to the database first");
            }
        }
 
        private bool OpenConnection(string server, string databaseName, string userid, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                string strConn = "server=" + server +
                                 ";database=" + databaseName +
                                ";uid=" + userid +
                                ";pwd=" + password;
                conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
                
 
            }
            return true;
        }
 
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
 
    }
}
```

The layout is as follows:

[image]

The effect is as follows:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot it's exactly what I was looking for but being a beginner I can't figure out where you have to put your information (server name, database name, id and password) in the code to ensure that you access.

Comment: @MirkoNastasi Hello, mainly by splicing strings and using [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to achieve

Comment: ok i will try now

Comment: thanks a lot it worked. now I should do the same thing in the same file next to it so with textbox5,6,7,8 and everything else (to connect to another server) do you know how to help me?

Comment: @MirkoNastasi Happy to help you. You need to repost a question and detail your requirements. Please add C# and Visual Studio to the Tag of the question

Comment: okay now i do thanks

Comment: i asked the new question just in time if you can go to see it

Comment: ok I'm already watching

Comment: @MirkoNastasi Hi, you need to describe the problem clearly. Although I know what you're going to do. But SO's moderation of questions is strict. If your question is closed then I cannot post my answer. Also, if you post a new question please tag Viusal Studio and C#.